# Symfony form, updating entity results in wrong argument type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form and I can create a new record in my database just fine.

Now I would like to update this record with the same form so I am loading the form with my entity from the database.

In this form there is a field called `modelBuild` and it is `nullable` and at the moment empty so when I load my form there is nothing in the field.

Until there this is straightforward

But now I try to update the database record so I send the form but the controller crashes at `$form->handleRequest($request);` saying:

`Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "modelBuild".`

I don't understand because this field has always been `null` so why is it complaining now ?

if I put something in the field then the form submits fine and the database is updated

ENTITY FIELD:

```
/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="model_build", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $modelBuild;

public function getModelBuild(): ?string
{
    return $this->modelBuild;
}

public function setModelBuild(string $modelBuild): self
{
    $this->modelBuild = $modelBuild;

    return $this;
}
```

TYPE

```
->add('modelBuild', TextType::class, array(
  'label' => 'model build',
))
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function formHandle(Request $request) {

    if ($this->usermgmt->isLogged()) {

        $update = json_decode($request->request->get('update'));

            $uid = $update[1];

            // get user
            $user = $this->usermgmt->getUser();

            $itemEntity = $em->getRepository(Item::class)->findOneBy([
                'uid' => $uid,
                'user' => $user
            ]);


        // create form
        $form = $this->createForm(NewItemType::class, $itemEntity);

        // handle
        $form->handleRequest($request);

     // rest of controller....
}
```

Comment: can you post your form please?

Comment: added the type. at the moment it looks like adding `null to ``@var string|null` seems to have solved the problem but that still looks freaky; I have no idea why this happened

Comment: I guess you dont need to set this null, nullable true it works only

Comment: yes that is what I'm thinking too and that is what I did to create the record in the first place but for some reason it seems to need this to update it for this particular field...  the form sends an empty string which should be interpreted as null

Comment: Can we see `modelBuild` setter in the entity?

Comment: added getter and setter

Answer (score 1):

The setter expects only a string and not accepting a null value. Change it to **?string**